# Showing $H=\{\log a : a\in \Bbb Q, a>0\}$ is a subgroup of $\left \langle \Bbb R,+ \right \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

**The Problem:** Let $G=\left \langle \Bbb R,+ \right \rangle$ and $H=\{\log a : a\in \Bbb Q, a>0\}$

Show that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

---

**My Proof:**

Let $\log a$ and $\log b$ be elements in $H$ where $a,b \in \Bbb R$ and $a,b>0$. Then $\log a + \log b=\log ab \in H$ since $ab\in \mathbb Q$ and $ab>0$. Thus $H$ is closed.

Let $-\log a =\log a^{-1} =\log({1\over a}) \in H$, then $\log a + (-\log a)=\log a - \log a=0$. Thus $-\log a \in H$ and $H$ has additive inverses and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

---

Note: I am specifically trying to prove $H$ is a subgroup by showing $H$ is closed and has inverses. What would happen to this result if $a$ was only allowed to be a natural number?

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle`, not `<` and `>`.

Comment: In the 2nd line, you should have "since $ab \in \mathbb{Q}$" instead of "since $ab \in H$".

Comment: Alternatively you could use isomorphism $\exp$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More or less, this proof is correct. My main nitpick is with your wording of showing inverses. You should say

> Let $\log a \in H$. Then [...] and thus $-\log a$ (the inverse of $\log a$ under $+$) is in $H$.

As worded, it seems to presuppose that this inverse is in $H$. Some other nitpicks could arise, such as (unless you know $\left \langle \Bbb R,+ \right \rangle$ is an *abelian* group specifically) needing to show the inverse works on each side.

Also, a minor thing: you should have that $\log a, \log b \in H$ because $a,b$ are specifically in $\Bbb Q^+$ (i.e. are positive rationals, not just real numbers). Perhaps it is also worth noting that you are assuming $\Bbb R, \Bbb Q$ are fields in this proof, with the usual properties - for instance, assumping that $a,b \in \Bbb Q \implies a \cdot b \in \Bbb Q$.

---

Also, note that you can use the [one-step subgroup test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/One-Step_Subgroup_Test) instead for a slightly slicker proof, in the sense that

$$\log a + (- \log b) = \log \left( \frac a b \right)$$

which is in $H$ since $a,b > 0 \implies b \ne 0$ and $a/b > 0$.

---

> What would happen to this result if $a$ was only allowed to be a natural number?

Then it would not work since you do not have inverses for every element. For instance, $2 \in \Bbb N \implies \log 2 \in H$ but it has inverse

$$-\log 2 = \log \left( \frac 1 2 \right)$$

which is not in $H$, since $1/2 \not \in \Bbb N$.

Comment: Thank you! The last equation is so weird to me. What you said makes perfect sense, but what throws me off is that the left hand side of the equation satisfies the condition and the right hand side doesn't, but they're equal to each other. What does this mean?

Comment: The condition is that any two members of the set must add together to give another member of the set. That's not always the case, though. Though in this case, it occurs to me that I probably used a bad example. I should say that, while $\log a \in H$ for every $a \in \Bbb N$, it's not always true that their inverse is, since $-\log a = \log(1/a)$. For instance, while $\log 2 \in H$, $\log(1/2) \not \in H$ because $1/2 \not \in \Bbb N$.